# sending strings as a parameter of a constructor to be shown in the dialog, Changing the string to table of info

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, overlay, android-dialog

I am using dialog and a there a class called OverlayItem which has a constructor that recive two strings to be shown in the dialog when pressing on that overlay.. 
I know that when defining the overlayItem we send two string to it. one is considered as a title to a dialog and the other one is considered as a content to the dialog.

Now I was thinking if a table of information not just a string is shown in the content of the dialog ( the second string) ??

The code

```
       OverlayItem overlayItem2 ; 
      overlayItem2 = new OverlayItem (Points2 , "STR1 " , "STR2") ;
```

I mean instead of STR2 I want to show a table in the dialog ??

Help please

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, you need to create custom overlay class , and use custom dialog t display  table. please  reffer below link for custom dailog.

[click here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dia)